# Converting Ycbcr Image to grayscale with Aforge.net

Tags: c#, aforge

I'm new to Aforge.net.
I have filtered and image with YCbCr filter with Aforge.Net

```
YCbCrFilter.Y = new Range(0, 1);
YCbCrFilter.Cb = new Range(-0.1862745098039216f, 0.0294117647058824f);
YCbCrFilter.Cr = new Range(0.0137254901960784f, 0.2254901960784314f);
// apply the filter
var YCbCrFilteredImage = YCbCrFilter.Apply(bitmap);
```

I need to convert the resulted image (i.e `YCbCrFilteredImage` ) to `Grayscale` image, to convert it later to black and white image.
So how can I do the converting to grayscale?

Comment: Use the Grayscale class.  This is rather basic, look around a bit before you ask a question.  http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/d7196dc6-8176-4344-a505-e7ade35c1741.htm

Comment: I searched alot actually, but I didn't understand how to set (r,g,b) values for this method. Thanks alot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Salam Ruba ,, use this grayscale values Grayscale(0.2125, 0.7154, 0.0721) and for thresholding the BradleyLocalThresholding is the best in this library. also instead of YCbCrFilter maybe you would like to use [HSL Filtering](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/743311a9-6c27-972d-39d2-ddc383dd1dd4.htm) and here is the code for you

```
    YCbCrFiltering YCbCrFilter = new YCbCrFiltering();
    YCbCrFilter.Y = new Range(0, 1);
    YCbCrFilter.Cb = new Range(-0.1862745098039216f, 0.0294117647058824f);
    YCbCrFilter.Cr = new Range(0.0137254901960784f, 0.2254901960784314f);
    // apply the filter
    var YCbCrFilteredImage = YCbCrFilter.Apply(bitmap);
    Grayscale gfilter = new Grayscale(0.2125, 0.7154, 0.0721);
    YCbCrFilteredImage = gfilter.Apply(YCbCrFilteredImage);
    BradleyLocalThresholding thfilter = new BradleyLocalThresholding();
    thfilter.ApplyInPlace(YCbCrFilteredImage);
```

you can search for blobs now ;)